# MySQL Search Query C# Forms

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a search bar that allows the user to search for their name at the end of a week. I have encountered an error, I want the user to not be allowed to look for their data if the day does not equal 7.

EDIT: **I know my database is vulnerable to SQL Injections, please disregard any suggestions relating to SQL Injections, this is purely for simplicity, I thank you for your concern though**

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dTable.Clear();
    String sQuery;
    sQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username LIKE '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' AND Day > 7'" + "'%'";
    updateDataGrid(sQuery);
}
```

To save time and to avoid bothering people with simple syntax errors I have tried to look for programs or websites that automatically check the syntax and fix it for you, this one is praised but it didn't offer a fix it just informed me of an error I had already known http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

If anyone knows of a program or a website that can fix your syntax for you please let me know, I'd much rather be able to learn from a website with common errors so that I can fix them in the future.

Comment: Due to the complexity of queries, it would be wiser, and better to just learn what the errors mean, and fix it yourself.

Comment: You should first take a look about SQL Injection, your data base information could easily be hacked.

Comment: I know Green Chili, I am trying to learn what they mean but it's complicated stuff and I don't know where to start, the SQL manuals are so confusing to start from

Comment: Like @Veelicus wrote, you will need to *escape* `txtSearch.Text` to prevent a security issue.

Comment: _"If anyone knows of a program or a website that can fix your syntax for you please let me know, I'd much rather be able to learn from a website with common errors so that I can fix them in the future"_ - that's not how this site works. "Show me a list of all errors and I'll learn how to prevent them" is not the way to ask a question here. Given one specific error, you can get factual answers. In fact, the question is bound to be answered before. One hint: you can spot the error by inspecting the `sQuery` variable.

Comment: @CodeCaster, thank you for your informative comment but I had already known that the error was in the query variable. The program told me there was a syntactical error within the query. You are just telling me things that I already know without giving any useful input.

Comment: I'm telling you you can't ask questions like that here, which you apparently didn't know.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Yeah I understand that you guys won't 'spoon-feed' me, I have solved my own problem further down.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out, after spending sometime on MySql database using the SQL Queries I transfered the information over to my C# program and got a working query

```
 "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' AND `Day` >= 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

it should done like this.

```
sQuery = @"SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username LIKE CONCAT('%',@Search,'%') AND Day > CONCAT(@Number,'%')";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", txtSearch.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", Number);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```